# Where is the source code for the UIComponent in FLEX 4.5?

Tags: actionscript-3, flex4.5

All the methods in UIComponent, LayoutManager (and I suppose more) are unimplemented. Why? and how to find it?

I use the lastest version of flashDeveloper. The flex package is downloaded by the app itself,  and I saw is version 4.5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FlashDevelop has a keyboard shortcut that will take you to the class definition.  I think it's something like F4, but I don't use it on a daily basis.

UIComponent has a lot of unimplemented methods because it's sort of like a smucky abstract class-ish thing.

Comment: I know but in past I've been used flex4, and I had access to the source-code and implemented methods.

Comment: You should still have access to the source code, in the SDK folder.  I believe FlashDevelop's keyboard shortcut should find it fine, but if not, use Ctrl-F to find it in Windows Explorer.

Comment: I see the source, but the methods are unimplemented:public function get width () : Number;public function set width (value:Number) : void; They are just like Interfaces!

Comment: Yes, that's what I said.  It's like a smucky Abstract Class.  The implementation is up to the subClass.  I think they've moved even more stuff out to subclasses in Flex 4, but they never did implement much in there.

Comment: For more on abstract classes, see: http://dispatchevent.org/mims/abstract-classes-in-as3/

Comment: But in the svn of adobe I found the implmented classes with all their methods.. only in the sdk are not implmented